# Redirect without changing the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I would like to implement the following functionality with RoR.

Site B is requesting something for site A:

```
http://sitea.com?test=1&test2=2&test3=3 [From SiteB to SiteA]
```

Site A pass the request untouched to site C:

```
http://sitec.com?test=1&test2=2&test3=3 [From SiteA to SiteC]
```

Site C returns results to Site A which returns results to Site B.

Is that possible with Rails?

Something like a proxy?

EDIT: I am interested for the controller of site A, the site in the middle!

Answer (score 0):

.. for simple GET requests, you could do:

Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'httparty'
...
```

config/routes.rb:

```
...
match '*p', :to => 'forward#index'
...
```

app/controllers/forward_controller.rb:

```
Class ForwardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => HTTParty.get(request.url).body
  end
end
```